# TensorFlow - How to compute gradient while ignoring zero weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, deep-learning

I want to implement pruning by setting some weights to 0.0 (specific weights in each layer, selected in a way that is not important to discuss here) to (1) ignore them during inference and (2) ignore them during training.

I know I can ignore them during inference by applying a mask to each layer, with ones at the indices of weights I want to keep and zeros otherwise.

During training, however, I want the ignored weights to remain ignored. That is, I want them to (1) not be updated and (2) not affect the computation of the rest of the gradients.

I can do (1) by masking the gradients before applying them. But I can't do (2).

I've tried something like this:

```
# Create an optimizer.
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)

# Compute the gradients for a list of variables.
# This returns a list of tuples, each tuple containing gradients and
# the corresponding variable
[(var, grad)] = opt.compute_gradients(loss)

# Ask the optimizer to apply the capped gradients.
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad * mask, var)])
```

But this doesn't do what I'm after, because `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)` will calculate loss **based on all weights, including the ones that are zero**. In other words, `grad` will have some gradients that correspond to indices where weights are zeros. Applying a mask "wastes" these gradients that should have been used to update non-zero weights.

I want it to calculate loss based on non-zero weights.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you apply a mask to your "ignored" weights (i.e. multiply them by a fixed value 0) to compute `loss`? If that is the case, they clearly don't contribute to `loss` and also their gradient will be 0 (as the last term in the chain rule corresponds to the mask coefficient, which is 0 for the ignored weights).

Comment: @rvinas You're right! The problem was this: to determine how many weights were 0 after re-training, I used a direct comparison like `tf.not_equals(Weights, tf.zeros_like(Weights)`. However, the ignored weights did receive a very small gradient, ending up with values like 1e-30, which is not counted as equal to 0. In light of this, what is the smallest value we can safely consider to be "effectively" zero?

Comment: I don't know where's the threshold, but a value of 1e-30 is negligible and acceptable from my point of view.